# How to get my branch name from a pre-receive hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I am working with GitHub enterprise and I don't have permissions to upload new pre-receive hooks to our repo.

I tried to test my hook as a pre-push hook and it was working like a charm,
but when I sent my hook to our admin he said: **"The GitHub pre-receive-hook script is different with git pre-receive-hook script. The git symbolic-ref --short HEAD may not work as your expected"**

So I need to find a way to replace this command:

```
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) || exit 1
```

To a command that will save my current branch inside "current_branch" parameter?

How do I do that without the ability to test it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, when using the stdin you can get the CURRENT_BRANCH from the 1st argument "$refname" :

```
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    echo "$refname : $oldrev ~ $newrev"
done
```

If you want to chop and clean it using sed you can just add this:

```
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    echo "$refname : $oldrev ~ $newrev"
    current_branch=$refname
    short_current_branch="$(echo $current_branch | sed 's/refs\/heads\///g')"
done
```

And you will get just the name of the branch inside a parameter **(short_current_branch)**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A pre-receive hook is a hook running in a *different Git*.  Your current branch in *your* Git is irrelevant, and in a pre-receive hook, *their* Git's current branch is irrelevant too.  Whatever your actual task is, using "the current branch" is going to be wrong.

(Their Git's current branch *may* be relevant in a post-receive hook, if that hook's job is to deploy updates to the current branch.  However, note that receiving Gits are generally configured as "bare" repositories.)